# How to create hexagonal view menu in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-custom-view, android-custom-attributes

I am intended to create a hexagonal view menu with icons as mentioned in the image below. I have tried to use the [library](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview/%22like%22/%22library%22) from github for imageview but it doesn't suits me for my requirement, what i all need is the hexagon view with the click events in a particular hexagon area. The library gives hexagonal view for single image target, but considered for the hexagonal menu it fails to give the hexagon output(i.e. i couldnt able to align it properly in my layout).

Please help me with your suggestions for the improvement in layout or through code. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: This view can be drawn using canvas or use an image from drawable and set it on a canvas at specific x y coordinates. Obviously, a mathematical calculation would be required

Comment: Thanks Rahul gupta. Is there any other way to create?? I guess drawing canvas takes much of time as compated to just aligning the positions with drawables in layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have tried to create the layout that u required, using ImageViews, LinearLayout and applying the negative margin.

I am not sure if it is the ideal way to use, but i guess you can give it try if don't want go for canvas.

Please go through the below example...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-25dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12.5dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa"
            android:visibility="invisible"
/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-25dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-25dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12.5dp"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-25dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hexa"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

here `drawable/hexa` is single white hexagonal png image.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks nDroidDev. This is what i need. But i guess problem may occur while touching the corner edges. Click event may get collapsed. Do you have any solution to handle that??

Comment: Glad to help.. and about the click event.. since the images are invisible , it should not affect the others' click listener..Or set `clickable=false` for invisible images and `true` for visible images and then try

Answer (score 1):

The below attached code for hexagon view. Change the button image for your convinence

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="com.example.me.testapplication.Buttons">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="211dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cell"></Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cell" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll3"
    android:layout_width="216dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"

    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ll2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cell"></Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cell" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"

    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ll1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/cell"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cell" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/cell" />
</LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's how I have achieved the same UI using `ConstraintLayout`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.MyFragment">

    <com.myapp.widget.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/iv_1"
        style="@style/tv_style"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/honey_comb_center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Total\nInvestment"
        app:fontName="@string/font_bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/honey_comb"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/iv_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/honey_comb"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/iv_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/honey_comb"
        android:translationY="@dimen/_20sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/iv_1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/iv_2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/iv_1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/honey_comb"
        android:translationY="@dimen/_20sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/iv_1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/iv_1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/iv_3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/honey_comb"
        android:translationY="@dimen/_minus20sdp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/iv_2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/iv_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/honey_comb"
        android:translationY="@dimen/_minus20sdp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/iv_1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/iv_3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/iv_1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is the screenshot
[image]